# passing element by id works with pure javascript but fails with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have this pretty simple piece of code where i get a certain id and what im trying to do is to change the element's css.
the code looks like this:

```
<script>
 jQuery('.sitePick').click(function(event){
   var site = (event.target.href.split("#")[1]); // get the id
   console.log(site); // make sure i get the correct id
   jQuery('#' + site).css("display" , "block"); //change css
});
</script>
```

the log prints the correct id of the element, and when i tried t use the same id like this : `docuemnt.getElementById(site).style.display = "block"`
it worked, but not when using jQuery.
what worries me the most its that even when i passed the id as is ( `jQuery("#dummySite")` to jQuery it still didn't work..any idea what i'm doing wrong? thx

**UPDATE**

the value of site is "site_buzzy.com". 
I am loading jquery right at the beginning of the file, other jquery methods work.the script being loaded after the content.

Comment: What's the value of `site`, coz generally integers or values starting with integers are known to cause problems. Also, 1. are you loading jQuery, 2. loading the script after loading jQuery, and thirdly, 3. loading the script after the content has been loaded?

Comment: Try using `jQuery('#' + site).show();`.

Comment: are you sure that the DOM is loaded when `jQuery('.sitePick').click(...)` is called ? to do so wrap your code with `$(function(){   });`

Comment: Your code is working https://jsfiddle.net/rmg69eL7/

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9z6q4e2p/1/ ?

Comment: doc ready wrapper needed.......i guess this is something easy to understand @yarivbar

Comment: @jai, true, this isn't always event.target, but in this scenario, event.target will have already been visible anyway, so it wasn't my code that didn't make sence it's OP's.. js

Comment: in fact i bet that's OP problem.. he's probably expecting something to change but this code wouldn't change anything anyway..

Comment: @Pamblam Your code made visible the clicked one, not retrieving id from an href property ... OP code make sence

Comment: @Pamblam It wasn't Jai than suggested diff between `event.target` and `this` :)  I was just making a side note btw, i din't downvoted your answer even Jai was correct, it didn't really make sense

Comment: @A.Wolff `event.target` is the element that was clicked. how could the user have clicked it if it wasn't visible..

Comment: @Hacketo yes I made a css call to the element being targetted, which is **exactly what OP's code is doing** u get it?

Comment: like i said, OP's code is perfectly fine, the problem is that he's trying to make an element visible that is already visible.. do you people understand now..

Comment: @OP so you need to escape dot (.) in some way... Would have been fixed long time ago if only you'd have posted a MCVE...

Comment: @Pamblam No, that's not the issue as i can see it. Because why anyway would js plain way would work?

Comment: after reading the update i don't think so either.. meh i give up

Comment: @Pamblam the css call is not on `element.target` , `jQuery('#' + site)` is not `this`

Comment: yeah i see that my.. my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape dot(s) in some way to use `site` string as jQuery selector.

```
var site = (event.target.href.split("#")[1]).replace(/\./g, "\\.");
```

Now this could be simplified to:

```
var site = event.target.hash.replace(/\./, "\\."); // get the id
jQuery(site).show();
```

```js
jQuery('.sitePick').click(function(event) {
  var site = event.target.hash.replace(/\./, "\\."); // get the id
  jQuery(site).show(); //change css
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="sitePick" href="#site_buzzy.com">Site Pick</a>
<br />
<div id="site_buzzy.com" class="hidden">The DIV #site_buzzy.com</div>
```

Comment: @Ianis No, you want as IDstring: `#site_buzzy\.com`